Calculating the fixed-point representation of (1 - SQRT(0.5)) to arbitrary levels of precision
I have a constant 0.29289321881345247559915563789515..., which can be calculated using the equation (1 - SQRT(0.5)) and then transformed into fixed-point format in order to be used with various sizes of unsigned integers. See the following table for examples:



Word Size
Q Format
Decimal Value
Binary Value




8-bit
Q0.3
5
101


16-bit
Q0.7
75
1001011


32-bit
Q0.15
19195
100101011111011


64-bit
Q0.31
1257966796
1001010111110110000110011001100


128-bit
Q0.63
5402926248376769403
100101011111011000011001100110000000110001000011001101101111011



The problem is that calculating these values becomes infeasible due to the fact that it involves the square root function and numbers that can get arbitrarily large. I remember learning about a "spigot algorithm" that outputs the digits of π using a bounded amount of memory and was hoping that something similar exists for constants such as the one described above. This paper came up during my search, but I have not been able to grok it well enough to translate into code.
How can one accomplish this in a C-like language (preferably C#)? Is there a better way to accomplish the goal of calculating this value for word sizes that are a power of two?

Extra Context
I have the following C# snippet that is from another question:
y -= uint.CreateChecked(value: BinaryIntegerConstants<T>.Size) switch {
    8U => (x * ((y * T.CreateChecked(value: 5UL)) >> 4)),
    16U => (x * ((y * T.CreateChecked(value: 75UL)) >> 8)),
    32U => (x * ((y * T.CreateChecked(value: 19195UL)) >> 16)),
    64U => (x * ((y * T.CreateChecked(value: 1257966796UL)) >> 32)),
    128U => (x * ((y * T.CreateChecked(value: 5402926248376769403UL)) >> 64)),
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException(), // TODO: Research a way to calculate the proper constant at runtime.
}

I have manually calculated the constants above by using C# code, but cannot go any further due to the limits of the double type.

You need to ask a more specific question, like identify the part of the paper that's confusing you. Otherwise, it seems like you're just asking someone to write the code for you.

How large is 'arbitrarily large'? Is it so large that you can't set up one large bit array, and use the appropriate n bits?

@Barmar Sure, see the example in section 3 of the paper? It makes absolutely zero sense to me because the value of the square root of 7 is 2.6457513... the example doesn't seem to even remotely resemble that and so I've ended up quite confused.

@WeatherVane Using C# generic maths, as large as is supported by at runtime. I have an implementation of integer square root that depends on this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282329/generic-integer-square-root.

Put the clarification in the question. Comments are ephemeral, the question is permanent.

No need to address your comments to me. I don't know anything about this area of math, I'm not planning on trying to answer the question.

c_n = 2^n - isqrt(2^(2n-1)) for your Q0.(n-1) representation I think. You can just use mpz_sqrt from gmp library to calculate arbitrary precision integer square roots. You might want to subtract one sometimes if you want a nearest rounded result.

@Kittoes0124 Sorry you had a bad experience. Since your question is about an algorithm (without showing any code to debug), you would be welcomed on other SE sites: https://math.stackexchange.com/ https://mathoverflow.net/ https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ https://cs.stackexchange.com/ It wasn't clear if 1 - SQRT(0.5) was the only number you needed or a general non-float function. If one, you can use a program to create a .h with predefined constants. Otherwise, there are other algs that may be better with fixed-point formats (e.g. binary search).

@Kittoes0124 I did a cursory look at the cited paper (and the Qx.y format). Just a guess, but it looks like spigot produces a stream of decimal digits (e.g. BCD). To convert this to Qx.y format that wants the numerator/denominator to be base 2(?) so that mul/div ops are shifting, there would be more calculation in the conversion than the actual spigot calculation (i.e. maybe not so useful). Also, note that spigot is worse than O(n^2) and Newton Raphson is better than that. N/R could operate on Qx.y directly, so maybe a better choice (likewise binary search).

@CraigEstey Thank you, I'll try one of them. As for the desired algorithm, performance is not relevant since we only need to calculate these values during compilation. All that really matters is that we avoid a dependency on a square root function that is limited.

@Kittoes0124 So, from your last comment, I infer that you only have a fixed/limited number of constants you need to generate? So, [as I mentioned] you can write a utility program that uses sqrt or whatever to generate the constants and put them into a [generated] myconstants.h file during the build process? In this context, I'm taking compilation literally (vs. during runtime initialization). This would be [beware ... trendy term] metaprogramming ...

@Yes, but the lengths are only known to the compiler. I'm implementing integer square root in such a way that the algorithm works for any possible word size. The problem with using sqrt is that A) the built-in sqrt function is limited to relatively small word sizes and B) we're implementing the unlimited version, so it can't depend on itself.

@Kittoes0124 Okay, so math.h version of sqrt et. al. doesn't have enough precision, so you want to create your own (e.g. mysqrt that could output a hundred digit number). That is, the limitation is precision and not the potential code bloat of libm.a at runtime. I guess my primary question is [still] whether you can do this (1) during the make/build process (on your development system) vs. (2) at runtime, by the running program [that may have limited resources, such as embedded].

@Kittoes0124 An alternative approach could be to generate your constants via a Python library with unlimited precision. E.g. sympy from sympy import sqrt; for k in [3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255]: print(f"Q0.{k}={((1 - 1 / sqrt(2)) * 2 ** (k + 1)).round()}")

@JohanC Thanks, though this is more or less how I calculated the constants I have. I need the solution to be internal to my language in order to support the contract of ISQRT<T> where T is structure that represents an abstract binary integer.

@Kittoes0124 So, given (e.g.) 1 - mysqrt(a), where (e.g.) a is, in your example, 0.5, how many different a values are we talking about (e.g. 1, 3, 9, 37)? And, for Qx.y format, how many different x/y pairs are we talking about (e.g Q8.15)? And, are the number of a values and x/y pairs known at compile/build time? Or, is this a library you'll give out to other developers and they can specify an arbitrary a value and an arbitrary Qx.y format in a call to your function?

@CraigEstey Oooh, I see the misunderstanding now. mysqrt is called with unsigned integer values that range from 0 to X where X is a power of two (2^8, 2^16, 2^32, etc; up to a limit determined by the type the library consumer uses). The challenge in building this function is that it depends on being able to calculate 1 - SQRT(0.5) in order to statically generate the correct constant. The Q formats are always of the form Q0.((X / 2) - 1) and completely determined by the supplied type. I hope this clarifies!

You absolutely require high performance arbitrary precision multiply to stand any chance of this working. Naive O(N^2) multiply gets slow very quickly when compared to the divide and conquer FFT style O(NlogN) version. For  N ints and N=10^9 the difference is 10^18 vs 3x10^10 machine cycles (or 10 years vs 10s). No algorithm that I know of can beat the no divide Newton-Raphson sqrt implementation and it can bootstrap itself up quadratically. You may as well start with a 64 bit seed sqrt value from a long double sqrt but if you must start from a 2^N rational 181/256 is as good as any.

I reached out to Daniel Lemire and he was not only gracious enough to help me work out the following solution but wrote a blog post about it too.
public static class BinaryIntegerExtensions
{
    /// <returns>
    /// The result of (1 - SQRT(0.5)) in the fixed-point format Q0.((X >> 1) - 1) where X is the number of bits in type T.
    /// </returns>
    public static T ComputeOneMinusSquareRootOfOneHalf<T>() where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte)) { return T.CreateChecked(value: 5); }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ushort)) { return T.CreateChecked(value: 75); }

        var @base = (T.One << 8);
        var length = ((T.PopCount(value: T.AllBitsSet) >> 4) + T.One);
        var power = (T.One << 1);
        var result = T.Zero;

        do {
            if (power < ((result << 1) + T.One)) {
                power *= (@base * @base);
                result *= @base;
            }
            else {
                power = ((power - (result << 1)) - T.One);
                result += T.One;
            }
        } while (result < @base.Exponentiate(exponent: length));

        return ((@base.Exponentiate(exponent: (length - T.One)) - ((result / @base) >> 1)) - T.One);
    }
    public static T Exponentiate<T>(this T value, T exponent) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
        var result = T.One;

        do {
            if (T.IsOddInteger(value: exponent)) {
                result *= value;
            }

            exponent >>= 1;
            value *= value;
        } while (T.Zero < exponent);

        return result;
    }
}

Example:
BinaryIntegerExtensions.ComputeOneMinusSquareRootOfOneHalf<byte>();    // 5
BinaryIntegerExtensions.ComputeOneMinusSquareRootOfOneHalf<ushort>();  // 75
BinaryIntegerExtensions.ComputeOneMinusSquareRootOfOneHalf<uint>();    // 19195
BinaryIntegerExtensions.ComputeOneMinusSquareRootOfOneHalf<ulong>();   // 1257966796
BinaryIntegerExtensions.ComputeOneMinusSquareRootOfOneHalf<UInt128>(); // 5402926248376769403


I don't know of a spigot algorithm for binary or hexadecimal sqrt(1/2) but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist. It isn't my field but I am interested in PLSQ which can handle similar approximation problems.
The BPP algorithm you recall for pi is something of a peculiarity. In that it is possible to compute isolated digits of the hexadecimal representation of pi correctly using a very specific formula obtained by sophisticated computer assisted high precision experimental mathematics. It was a big surprise when it was discovered in 1995. Later papers on PLSQ and LLL still use its derivation as an example of the power of newer faster integer relations and lattice reduction algorithms.
There is however the option of Newton-Raphson available in a form that doubles the number of significant digits each time you use it and can work in scaled integer arbitrary precision form if you are careful about it.
Wanting a precise sqrt(1/2) is particularly helpful here. Multiplies and divides by 2 are trivial in base 2.
I think there may be a way forward for you using a scaled integer version of an old Newton-Raphson based method for computing 1/sqrt(y) where y in this case is 2. The reciprocal square root algorithm works as follows and dates to before there was FP hardware support for doing it quickly. Some cbrts still use this method which neatly avoids doing a slow division. Divisions remain pretty slow today when compared to all of the other binary operations. Below is the simple derivation of rsqrt()
f(x)  = y - 1/x^2
f'(x) = 2/x^3

Let the starting guess be x0 then NR iteration gives
x1 = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0)

x1 = x0 - (y - 1/x0^2)*x0^3/2  = x0 - x0*(y*x0^2-1)/2

Then set y = 2 (your special case) when the NR formula for simplifies further
x1 = x0 - x0*(x0*x0-1/2)  (#1)

x1 = 1 - 1*(1 - 1/2)    = 1/2
x2 = 1/2 - 1/2*(1/4-1/2) = 5/8
x3 = 3/4 - 5/8*(25/64-1/2) = 355/512

and with this you can double the number of accurate bits every iteration.
The computation cost is relatively modest 2 * and 2 - computed at twice the length of the previous result.
But be careful of the last few bits at any fixed depth since although the algorithm is self correcting there could be a carry from the next stage that affects several bits in the least significant part of the present one.
I know that (#1) can be rewritten as but it is less accurate in that form (at least in normal FP work)
 x1 = x0*(3/2-x0*x0)  (#1a)

You could also do it with Halley's method but that requires a non-trivial division at full working precision and so is bound to be slower here.
I would be inclined to precompute these values in an environment that allows easy access to fast arbitrary precision floating point like Julia or Python and import them as needed at runtime in the C# program
